# Objective-C: alloc of object within init of another object (memory management)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

In my `.h file` I have:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

My `.m file` looks basically like this:

```
@synthesize myArray;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.myArray = .... ? // here I want to create an empty array
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [self.myArray release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

What I'm not sure about is what do to in the `init`.

1)

```
self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

2)

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.myArray = tmp;
[tmp release];
```

Solution 1 doesn't seem right to me, because of my `@property (retain)` setting I automatically increase the retain counter when setting self.myArray, but additionally I have already a "+1 retain" due to the `[NSMutableArray alloc]` and then ending up with a retain count of 2 for that object, but only releasing once in the `dealloc`. Thus the second solution seems more correct to me, even though it is cumbersome.

Also am I wondering if `self.myArray = ...` is actually the same as `[self setMyArray:...]` and thus does increase the retain count.

**UPDATE**

I actually found the answers (and even more details) [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7295-getters-setters-properties-newbie.html) in case anyone is interested in reading more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.myArray =` is exactly the same as `[self setMyArray:...]`.

You could however do `myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` which would end up with a retain count of 1 and would be totally legit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `self.myArray = ...` is the same as `[self setMyArray:...]`

So the set process adds a redundant retain to your object.  You should probably release it immediately after the set, although I have seen some code that uses autorelease, one way or another.  Both approaches are awkward.

Avoiding the set accessor (`myArray = ...`) is possible, but bypassing accessors is also frowned on by purists.

Comment: It's generally considered fine to bypass the accessor in the init method.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the convenience methods returning autoreleased instances:

```
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```